# Why id() of a method changes after I call the hex() function?

Tags: python

The `id()` function gives different values for the same method, and I don't know why.

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
>>> class Test():
...     def test(self):
...         pass
...
>>> a = Test()
>>> id(a.test), id(a.test), id(a.test), hex(1), id(a.test)
(1662807685632, 1662807685632, 1662807685632, '0x1', 1662813074048)
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ why was it changed?
```

This gives weird effects:

```py
>>> id(a.test) == id(a.test)
True
>>> hex(id(a.test)) == hex(id(a.test))
False
```

Is it intended? Tested with Python 3.11.4.

Comment: Presumably it has something to do with descriptors creating a new bound method object each time `a.test` is invoked.

Comment: Exactly. `hex()` is a distraction -- it just means you've got different memory contents so you aren't getting the same pointer locations for transient objects.

Comment: It's more informative to say `a = Test(); t1 = a.test; t2 = a.test; id(t1) == id(t2)` -- you get a `False` comparison with no `hex()` involved anywhere; the fact that you saw a `True` is just because you let the first `a.test` be garbage collected when you failed to retain a reference to it so a second `a.test` could get the same memory location.